# Is it possible to set a single key—not a function key—to switch input methods on a US keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, ime, japanese

I have the U.S. version of the Apple Magic Keyboard, and occasionally use the Japanese input method with it.

Currently I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to switch languages, but it's a bit of a hassle. Is there a way to map it to a single key? For example to right <kbd>command</kbd> or right <kbd>option</kbd>?

I’ve been able to map it to <kbd>F5</kbd> but it's not as convenient as a key on the bottom.